# Missing Key word SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm getting an error message saying that i am missing a keyword. however, i can't see what i am missing. any help guys ?

Here is the code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW viewHolidayID
SELECT
DECODE (Country_Visted, 'USA','America',
        'India', 'Asia',
        'China', 'Asia',
        'Spain', 'Europe') AS continental, Package_Code, Description, Country_Visted FROM tbl_Holiday_Details;
SELECT * FROM viewHolidayID;
```

Comment: `AS` is missing after viewname

Answer (score 2):

The [syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_8004.htm#SQLRF01504) is `CREATE ... viewHolidayID  AS select ...`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW viewHolidayID 
AS
SELECT
 DECODE (Country_Visted,
          'USA'   , 'America',
          'India' , 'Asia',
          'China' , 'Asia',
          'Spain' , 'Europe'
        ) AS continental,
 Package_Code,
 Description,
 Country_Visted
FROM tbl_Holiday_Details;
```